# While converting String to Double toDouble() skips 0

Tags: android, kotlin, double, data-conversion

I am trying convert String value into Double.
But toDouble() automatically removing 0 from output value.
If String value is "1.30" then after conversion toDouble() returns 1.3.

````
val value = String.format(
            "%02d.%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milli) % 24,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milli) % 60
        )
    return value.toDouble()```

Input value : "1.30"
Retuned value : 1.3
Expected value : 1.30


Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: 1.3, 1.30, 1.300, 1.3000 is all the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert double to string with no zero absent in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74236305/how-to-convert-double-to-string-with-no-zero-absent-in-kotlin)

Comment: I want to return value in "double" type only...